# Instantiating Set of Sets in Java?

Tags: java

I want to instantiate a Set of Sets (of strings), and then place two `Set<String>`'s into it, like below:

```
Set<String> setOne = retrieveSetOne();
Set<String> setTwo = retrieveSetTwo();
Set<Set<String>> myCollection = new HashSet<new HashSet<String<()>(); // not working
myCollection.add(setOne);
myCollection.add(setTwo);
```

Problem is, my instantiation of the nested set does not work. How do I do this?

Comment: `myCollection = new HashSet<Set<String>>()` is what you need.

Comment: Note that this is likely to blow up if you modify either of the contained sets, since that will affect the equality check performed by the containing set.

Answer (score 5):

change it to

```
Set<Set<String>> myCollection = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
```

you initialize by implementation when you create instance, for type you need to match declaration,

If you are on Java7 already then you can simply use

```
Set<Set<String>> myCollection = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Damn, Those >100k users with ultra fast typing... 
I was still reading when you gave the answer \o/

Comment: :) <!---------------->

Comment: @JigarJoshi - Btw, are you working as a Java dev or some other position ?

Comment: @Kyllopardiun not there yet https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79305/fastest-answers-in-all-tags

Comment: Isn't it `new HashSet<>();` in Java7? Type inference?

Comment: yes its in 7, I mentioned that, @james refer the profile

Comment: @JigarJoshi I meant, your first and Java7 examples are one and the same. Shouldn't the latter be `new HashSet<>()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Set<String>> myCollection = new HashSet<new HashSet<String<()>();
```

Why instantiate the inner set? Since the inner sets are going to be instantiated at the time you call add(), this is superfluous and it's probably breaking your code.

I would have put something more like this:

```
Set<Set<String>> myCollection = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
```